How to position the two panels
I have a question about how to arrange 2 panels for one section.
Situation: I’m navigating through the settings and the page with user settings is causing me problems. Because there is a hierarchy there. How best to arrange 2 panels (1. List of settings, 2. Hierarchy) That said, I need to save the content on the page, and there's a large table.
I have an idea to close the settings list and open the hierarchy by pressing the button

So you're applying settings to users right? And the users can be found in groups? It would be good to know whether you can or need to apply a number of settings to a single user or not.

The way you show it in the screenshot is probably the only way to do it.
If your "tree view" is really that complex with multiple nested levels of groups and this many of them, providing the full vertical space to navigate them is appropriate.
With that fixed the other panels do not have much room for alternative arrangements.
If you provide a way of collapsing the settings sidepanel you might also consider to detach the "user settings editor" from the settings menu entirely. Then you have a fresh window with the hierarchy/treeview and the options table only. This allows adding menus and save/load functionality etc. without cluttering the rest of the settings with that stuff.
